# Making section headers link to local files

Tags: sectioning, links

I want to make the section titles in my document link to external files on my machine, so that when you click on the section title, an external document (a pdf-file) is opened. What is the nicest way to do this?

Comment: I guess one solution is:

\section{\href{../somefile.pdf}{Section Title}}

but is there a "better" way to do this?

Comment: Better in what respect?

Comment: In the sense that often, some solution which works is deprecated or frowned upon. Like the use of double dollars for equations, where \[ \] is a better solution. A solution is also better if it does not break other functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a `\hrefsection` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\hrefsection}{smom}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\section*{\href{#2}{#4}}}
   {\IfNoValueTF{#3}
     {\section{\href{#2}{#4}}}
     {\section[#3]{\href{#2}{#4}}}%
   }}
```

which replicates the behavior of `\section`:

```
\hrefsection*{file}{Title}
\hrefsection{file}{Title}
\hrefsection{file}[toc entry]{Title}
```